How to properly safely remove (hot-swap) HDD connected to LSI HBA card under Windows Server 2019
I have a LSI HBA 9400-16e connected to a 24-bay enclosure with HDDs in it and running Windows Server 2019 (only JBOD, no RAID). The enclosure backplane supports hot-swap.
I am doing manual cold backups by inserting the backup HDD to this enclosure. When the backup process is complete I would like to safely remove this disk without losing data.
Currently, before removing the disk I mark it as Offline in Disk Management tool, but when doing it I can see errors in the Event Log saying The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. the moment I set the disk Offline probably because I have the write caching enabled for this disk and disabling it should fix this problem.
But I'm wondering if it is possible to enable the Safely removal notification icon for this disk. I know there are some registry tricks to enable hot-swap for internal disks but these work for the disks managed by msahci/storahci/etc. drivers (for example the TreatAsInternalPort registry value) and I don't think this works for disks connected to the LSI HBA controller as they are using another driver - itsas35.
Is there any way to enable the Safely removal notification icon for disks connected to the LSI HBA controller? It would be much more convenient than disabling write caching and setting the disk Offline.
